# Imacros Creat facebook fanpages

Tags: javascript, imacros

I recorded an imacros script to creat a new facebook fanpage, but when i replay script, it aways showed: RuntimeError: element was not found. (Google search said: facebook random tags ID, buy Xpath also faild)

does anyone can help?

Comment: Try different ways of recording. If it fails via ID try CLASS property. If it fails again then record macro via Experimental recording. Un select ID recording.

Comment: Thanks. but it still difficult for me, can you write a script for me? I can pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

I have macros for creating and using fan pages automatically.
I have to update them every month or so because facebook changes the tags a lot!

1)Some tags change from refresh to refresh but its always one of 2-3 options so once you get them down its not that bad.
2) use experimental recording , it does a better job for some facebook elements
3) if you cant seem to work out the id tags use X/Y position for the problematic button.
4) The real problem with facebook comes later after you got the automation working. They stop loading random buttons and pages that they see you using with the automation and it is hard to overcome.